# Can you explain me how to create views in Cassandra with example

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7, cassandra-cli

How to create a views in Cassandra,Can you give me an example, which data is coming from two or more tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create views in Cassandra. Just like you can't do joins. It's not that kind of a database. With Cassandra you model your schema differently and you denormalize.

Comment: HI Theo,Thank you for your answer, Could you please give me an Example for how can we model the schema in Cassandra.

Comment: No, not with the information you have provided.

Comment: Hi Theo,

I have to retrieve the data from two tables,

Here are my two tables in Cassandra DataBase.

employee is keyspace,

Two tables:

1.emp:- "eno" is primay key,"username","password"

2.Dept:-"dno" is primary key ,"eno","dname"

Now i want to retrieve the data from two tables,

Ex:-

eno,username,password,dno,dname


How can i retrieve data from two tabels.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As of Cassandra 3.0, it is now possible to create [Materialized Views](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views), although in truth, these are more like a 'synchronized table' and has storage and write overhead - whereas an non-materialized RDBMS view is essentially a projection function which only incurs cost when it is invoked.